# Send XML using SOAP - PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I need your help to send an XML through SOAP according to my provider's instructions.

Problems:

1. It does not generate the complete namespaces (Top xmlns: xsi and xmlns: xsd)
2. It does not generate the type of variable for the array fields (ns1: Value xsi: type = "xsd: string")

This is my code and the XML that generates me

```
$WebService = new SoapClient('https:url.asmx?wsdl', array( 'trace' => 1 ) );

$dateClient["PSEHostingField"][0] = array("Name"=>"id_client","Value"=>"123456789");
$dateClient["PSEHostingField"][1] = array("Name"=>"name_client","Value"=>"Daniel");
$dateClient["PSEHostingField"][2] = array("Name"=>"tel_client","Value"=>"123456");

$params = array(
    "ticketOfficeID" => 2259, 
    "amount" => 291944,
    "vatAmount" => 5444,
    "paymentID" => 9561,
    "paymentDescription" => PAGOS PSE,
    "referenceNumber1" => 10.10.10.244,
    "referenceNumber2" => NIT,
    "referenceNumber3" => 900000000,
    "serviceCode" => 5001,
    "email" => correocliente@gmail.com,
    "fields" => $dateClient,
    "entity_url" => "http:urlRespoce.php",
);

$Responce = $WebService->createTransactionPaymentHosting( $params );
```

This is the XML that throws me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.achcolombia.com.co/PSEHostingWS">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:createTransactionPaymentHosting>
            <ns1:ticketOfficeID>2259</ns1:ticketOfficeID>
            <ns1:amount>291944</ns1:amount>
            <ns1:vatAmount>5444</ns1:vatAmount>
            <ns1:paymentID>9561</ns1:paymentID>
            <ns1:paymentDescription>PAGOS PSE</ns1:paymentDescription>
            <ns1:referenceNumber1>10.10.10.244</ns1:referenceNumber1>
            <ns1:referenceNumber2>NIT</ns1:referenceNumber2>
            <ns1:referenceNumber3>900000000</ns1:referenceNumber3>
            <ns1:serviceCode>5001</ns1:serviceCode>
            <ns1:email>correocliente@gmail.com</ns1:email>
            <ns1:fields>
                <ns1:PSEHostingField>
                    <ns1:Name>id_client</ns1:Name>
                    <ns1:Value>123456789</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:PSEHostingField>
                <ns1:PSEHostingField>
                    <ns1:Name>name_client</ns1:Name>
                    <ns1:Value>Daniel</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:PSEHostingField>
                <ns1:PSEHostingField>
                    <ns1:Name>tel_client</ns1:Name>
                    <ns1:Value>123456</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:PSEHostingField>
            </ns1:fields>
            <ns1:entity_url>http:urlResponce.php</ns1:entity_url>
        </ns1:createTransactionPaymentHosting>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is the XML that I should send

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.achcolombia.com.co/PSEHostingWS">
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:createTransactionPaymentHosting>
            <ns1:ticketOfficeID>2259</ns1:ticketOfficeID>
            <ns1:amount>291944</ns1:amount>
            <ns1:vatAmount>5444</ns1:vatAmount>
            <ns1:paymentID>9561</ns1:paymentID>
            <ns1:paymentDescription>PAGOS PSE</ns1:paymentDescription>
            <ns1:referenceNumber1>10.10.10.244</ns1:referenceNumber1>
            <ns1:referenceNumber2>NIT</ns1:referenceNumber2>
            <ns1:referenceNumber3>900000000</ns1:referenceNumber3>
            <ns1:serviceCode>5001</ns1:serviceCode>
            <ns1:email>correocliente@gmail.com</ns1:email>
            <ns1:fields>
                <ns1:PSEHostingField>
                    <ns1:Name>id_client</ns1:Name>
                    <ns1:Value xsi:type="xsd:string">123456789</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:PSEHostingField>
                <ns1:PSEHostingField>
                    <ns1:Name>name_client</ns1:Name>
                    <ns1:Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Daniel</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:PSEHostingField>
                <ns1:PSEHostingField>
                    <ns1:Name>tel_client</ns1:Name>
                    <ns1:Value xsi:type="xsd:string">123456</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:PSEHostingField>
            </ns1:fields>
            <ns1:entity_url>http:urlResponce.php</ns1:entity_url>
        </ns1:createTransactionPaymentHosting>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have already tried a few tools like SOAPUI and the NUSOAP library and I have the same result, I get the following error:

> Type 'System.Xml.XmlNode' in Assembly 'System.Xml, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089 'is not marked as serializable.'

The provider tells me that it is because of the two problems I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in another source, the publication in case it served someone

Add SoapVar object

```
$datosCliente["PSEHostingField"][0] = array("Name"=>"id_client","Value"=>new SoapVar("123456789", XSD_STRING, "string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"));
$datosCliente["PSEHostingField"][1] = array("Name"=>"name_client","Value"=>new SoapVar("Daniel", XSD_STRING, "string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"));
$datosCliente["PSEHostingField"][2] = array("Name"=>"tel_client","Value"=>new SoapVar("123456", XSD_STRING, "string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"));
```